# Can a thread not block if the lock it tries to lock is not available?

Tags: parallel-processing

In OpenMP, there is routine `OMP_TEST_LOCK` which, when called by a thread to attempt to set a lock, but the thread does not block if the lock is unavailable.

I wonder what the calling a thread will do, if not block, when the lock it tries to lock is not available? Thanks!

Comment: This is a question about an implementation detail of a particular software library, and thus offtopic here. I'm moving it to [SO].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OMP_TEST_LOCK](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#OMP_TEST_LOCK) will indicate if a lock could be set via the return code.

Example:

```
if( omp_test_lock( &a_lock ) )
{
    work_a();
    omp_unset_lock( &a_lock ) )
}
else
{
    work_b();
}
work_c();
```

If the lock can be set, `work_a` and then `work_c` will be called. If the lock cannot be set, `work_b` and the `work_c` will be called. This is just the normal flow of control.

Comment: Thanks! But since the calling thread doesn't block, and can't lock the lock variable, what will the calling thread do?

Comment: what to run? For example?

Comment: @Tim Here you are. :)